# Google Forms very slow performance

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a google form that I am working on with some scripting done using GAS in the background that loads drop down lists with a lot of different info. The form itself is quite large, about 16 sections and it is loading and responding to scrolling up and down very slowly on several machines including my desktop computer which is a very powerful computer, so I don't think this is a machine dependent problem. Any tips to speed it up would be much appreciated, other than splitting the form into 2 forms or something similar to that.

Comment: Try testing the speed, switching off different parts of code, so you'll be able to see what exactly slows down the performance. Or, if you already know it, please share your sample code, so that it would be possible to  reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov I have completely commented out the onOpen trigger so there is no script running in the background.

Comment: the speed of a live Google Form has nothing to do with Apps Script / JS

Comment: @BryanP   the form editor itself is what is loading very slowly?

Comment: same deal, we can't change the code the controls the UI of the laggy drag and drop form builder. try downgrading to the old form builder if that's still an option or reporting to the appropriate [Google Product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/forms). Please specify if you are on the newer version of the builder there

Comment: mention the number of options connected to the dropdown item too

Comment: @BryanP this is exactly what I was looking for. Switching to the old forms instantly changed the performance by a lot. There were 25 drown down lists each with 300 or so entries. If you post this as an answer I will give you the bounty as that helped a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can temporarily downgrade to the old Google Form builder and see if that fixes the lag. Keep in mind that this changes all themes for any live forms back to the old ones too, so you may want to re-upgrade after making changes to the one giving you trouble.